# fetch data from two table with different column numbers and order them based on date

Tags: php, html

hi every body i have multiple  table  with different column number in my database. tables do not have any common column name except id and date. and if it is a problem i can change them too. now the problem is i want to fetch rows from this tables and order them by date. i write this code 
//table1
1, car1, 2016-07-02 00:00:00,price1,engine1
2, car2, 2016-07-05 00:00:00,price2,engine2
3, car3, 2016-07-07 00:00:00,price3,engine3
4, car4, 2016-07-08 00:00:00,price4,engine4
//table2
1, home1, 2016-07-03 00:00:00
2, home2, 2016-07-06 00:00:00
3, home3, 2016-07-09 00:00:00
//result
1, car1, 2016-07-02 00:00:00,price1,engine1
2, home1, 2016-07-03 00:00:00,,
3, car2, 2016-07-05 00:00:00,price2,engine
4, home2, 2016-07-06 00:00:00,,
5, car3, 2016-07-07 00:00:00,price3,engine3
6, car4, 2016-07-08 00:00:00,price4,engine4
7, home3, 2016-07-09 00:00:00,,
i wrote this code but it is not working well

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);

$mysqli=NEW MySQLI("localhost","root","","database");
mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysqli_query($mysqli,"SET character_set_connection='utf8'");
$resultset= $mysqli->query("SELECT table1.*,table2.*
    FROM table1 JOIN table2");
    echo $resultset->num_rows;
?>
```

please help thank you

Comment: Consider using union sql clause and aloas the price as 0 for the table that does not have this field

Comment: thank you for your answering i do not get could you plz explain a little more i am not familiar with union. could you please make a simple code

Comment: I'll add a solution tomorow, I am in the airport right now :))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your column names but this should do it:

```
select column_car, column_date, column_price, column_engine from table1
union
select column_home as column_car, column_date, NULL as column_price, NULL as column_engine from table2
```

In the second select I am aliasing NULL as the **price** and **engine** so that both selects would have ***the same result set***.

When using [union](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) both select statements must have the same column names and type.

You can specify where clauses in each select or a global where, depending on your needs :)

Comment: hi thank you for your answering. 
the reason i asked this question is this
i am desining advertising website and i have many ads from different cases like cars, realestate and electrical devises . thus i have 3 different tables with different column number in my database. one for each of them. this tables do not have any common column name except id and date. every table has more than 60 columns.. now the problem is i want to show all of ads in my first page of website and order them by date.

Comment: with this definition what do you think. what is the easiest way to solve this problem. because if i have to use above code i have to write every column name and it will be difficult

Comment: If you have different columns you can alias it no problem, so you would need to make another union and you can order by date. The problem would be that if your tables will grow the response time might grow as well...but you could get let's say 100 results (ordered by date) then cache them for 1 day.